# Bug in Excel? Shows a blank region although cells are not empty

Tags: excel

I have a page with some 300 rows, and they are all populated with formulas and values.
When I scroll downwards all is well but suddenly there is a blanc region. However, if I click some cell in that region, a small region appears with all its values. Then I click again and some more cells appear but I simply cannot see the whole page. Is this a bug? Is there a workaround? Thank you!

Comment: Hi JSP, your question is a bit vague, can you maybe provide a screenshot with a before and after. Furthermore, what are the settings (number/date/general/text) and which version of Excel do you use?

Comment: I can even input values on those "blank" cells, these values show up in the formula bar but they disappear as I press Return. The colour of the text is set to automatic.

Comment: Thank you Tox. I have a screen dump (png) but I to show it here?

Comment: You can press edit on your question and than you will be able to include a screenshot (image).

Comment: Version 15.38 for Mac (all new Mac and all new Excel).

Comment: Nope, I am new here so I cannot post images. Not much to see though, just an all blank rectangle in the middle of the sheet.

Comment: I think this problem is related to another problem. These three pages in the same workbook come from a much larger workbook where I got the message "Too many formats". So I reduced it to three sheets. I just tried to format some cell to Number rather than General and it displays the same message (for this small workbook!) It seems Excel remembers the old problem!? I would like to remove all formats from its memory and start afresh. But how?

Answer (score 2):

Select the range where you would like to delete the format. Than click the Home tab, in the Editing group (right on Microsoft Excel), click the arrow next to the Clear button,  and click clear format.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. That is, I cleared the format of all subsheets (not so many here) and now I can re-format some. The blank rectangles do not appear anymore (and I hope it will be like that forever). For the larger workbook, I will develop a VBA macro. BTW As a new person here, I cannot upgrade your answer but I suppose I can type it here: It was much valuable! Thank you very much @Tox.